# How to execute a BADI in BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST from C#?

Tags: sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector, badi

I have to pass data to BAdI `acc_document` in parameter `extension1` of BAPI `bapi_acc_document_post`, but I don't know how to do that using SAP .NET connector.

Any suggestions?

Regards, Devinder

Comment: Read the [programming guide](http://logosworld.com/docs/SAP/Connector/SAP%20Connector%20for%20Microsoft%20.NET%20%20NCo_30_ProgrammingGuide.pdf).

Comment: I have developed gr, po,invoice and service invoice getting and posting data to sap but in some cases we need to execute a badi to update some value in a table that are not updated through bapi. I have created a structure of badi but then I have to pass it as a parameter  to extension1. I don't  know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

BAPI extension parameters are pretty much free-form - as you can see, for `BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST` parameters `EXTENSION1` and `EXTENSION2` are defined as tables with character fields.

You can store whatever data you want to into them and use them as you do any other BAPI parameters, the key is that you need to *interpret* the values in your enhancement. For example, if the caller stores an external document number into a row of `EXTENSION1`, just interpret it as a document number when you use it in your BADI. If you're passing a structure in the extension parameter it can be a little trickier (as you have multiple fields to deal with), but the same principle applies.